# How to retrieve chinese character from MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, mybatis

I'm using Mybatis to retrieve data from MSSQL.

I set

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
<properties url="file:~~~~~~my file location"/>
<environments default="source">
    <environment id="source">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=sampleDB;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;" />
            <property name="username" value="test" />
            <property name="password" value="test" />

        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>

<mappers>
    <mapper url="file:${source.query.file}" />  
</mappers>
```

I set xml above. 
If I select some information, Java saves them as map with the code below.

```
ResultContext context;
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)context.getResultObject();
```

everything works fine except, if the result is chinese, I can see a bunch of symbol('?') not chinese character.

How can I fix this

Comment: are you sure if it is the retrieval or the printing?

Comment: Please post the code how you are getting(printing)  the results so that we can see the symbols that you see.

Comment: Where exactly you see the '?'.. If it's the console, likely its not a problem with code. In case of Windows OS, you need to install a language pack to render the fonts.